Strapi transfer command fails with Authorization Error despite valid transfer token
I'm trying to transfer data from my deployed Strapi instance to my local using the strapi transfer command. Despite using a newly created transfer push token, I'm encountering an authorization error.
Command used:
strapi transfer --from https://[my-strapi-instance].strapiapp.com/admin

Error received:
Copy[2024-10-22 10:06:35.278] [FATAL] Failed to initialize the connection: Authorization Error
Transfer process failed.

What could cause this authorization error even with a valid transfer token and url?
Are there any specific permissions or settings I need to check?
Strapi version: 4.24.0
